# How can I programatically write simple data into a complicated .xlsm document without destroying it?

Tags: python, ruby, excel

I have a very complicated Excel workbook in `.xlsm` format, with macros, named ranges, all the bells and whistles. I need to get the contents of a CSV file into a sheet (that already exists) in this workbook, in the simplest possible sense: row 1 column 1 goes to cell A1, row 1 column 2 goes to cell A2, and so on. You can accomplish this in Excel with a simple import or copy-paste, but I need to do it programmatically.

I need to do this using freely available software on Linux (actually CentOS 5, which further restricts my options, but let's not worry about that for now). Ideally I would use a ruby or Python library, but I'm open to anything at this point.

I do not know much about Excel, but here is some output that I see when I try to use `openpyxl` (which has worked well for me with simpler workbooks) to accomplish this:

```
/opt/python-assessment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:322: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
/opt/python-assessment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:322: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
/opt/python-assessment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.py:125: UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name
  warnings.warn("Discarded range with reserved name")
```

I don't know what any of that means, but the upshot is that `openpyxl` butchers the workbook when I try to *write* it, even if I haven't made any changes. I've tried the following approaches:

- `openpyxl` in Python: see above, appears to work (with warnings) but the resulting file is broken.
- `roo` in ruby: it was not obvious to me whether this library can write; at the very least, it seems to be primarily oriented towards reading.
- `spreadsheet` in ruby: I get this error when trying to open the file (perhaps it does not support the `.xlsm` format at all?): `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.8/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:378:in 'validate!': OLE2 signature is invalid (Ole::Storage::FormatError)`
- Manual unzipping and hackery of the file: the schema was complicated enough that it wasn't immediately obvious how to accomplish my goal. I still think this may be the best option, but I'll need to find a better reference or spend more time scratching my head to make progress.

At this point I'll pursue any approach that seems promising.

Comment: Here's another gem, and the development on it is fresh https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL

Comment: You can add a data connection to the csv directly in Excel and, I imagine, automate refreshing the connection.

Comment: If you are to retro-engineer it, I would suggest creating a simple workbook (one-sheet, saved as xlsm as well) and check that one out. From what I could see, the data in stored in xml tags under sharedStrings.xml, but then you'll also need other references under worksheets sheetx.xml

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP is asking for a solution working on Linux, however I ran into a similar problem on my Windows PC.

After struggling to get it working with openpyxl, xlutils and the like. I stumbled on a suggestion to manipulate files using a COM interface (using win32com.client).

So for anyone lucky enough to work on windows, please see the link below to get started:

http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/